# UITableView: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know there are many questions like that but I try all of the solutions and I am still getting this error.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sec=controller1.sections
    let secinfo=sec![section]

    return secinfo.numberOfObjects 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete){
        let  delet = controller1.object(at:indexPath)

        context.delete(delet)

        self.mytabel1.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)

        ad.saveContext()
    }
}
```

Comment: There are also many suitable answers: **You have to remove the item also from the data source array**.

Comment: what  did u mean . i think i already did that as u see

Comment: No, you didn't, you delete the object in CoreData and in the table view, but it still exists in the corresponding `secinfo` array.

Comment: ok if u don't mind can u give me the code

Comment: Please figure it out yourself. That's very basic stuff. Like in `numberOfRowsInSection` get the section (for `indexPath.section`) and remove the item at `indexPath.row`.